# Bigint: Failed to load bindings | tsconfig.json - cannot read file

Tags: javascript, typescript, blockchain, solana, bigint

I been having this error for the last 12 hours where when I go to compile my code I get this message in the powershell terminal :

"bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)"

I used chatgpt to work through the errors. It tells me to run npm run rebuild, which it successfully build and then after trying to compile my code again continue to get the same error.

I done all of the basic trouble shooting stuff such as restarting from stratch, removing and reinstalling all environment packages and using different versions of nodejs.

I pushed my file folder on github here:

https://github.com/Sam-Blade/Bladecoin-Bignt-Error

My goal is for the code to compile completely so it updates my metadata on Solana's testnet.

Im following this youtuber tutorial: How to create Silly Dragon Tokens [Solana Metaplex Tutorial] - Dec 21st '23 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vrZ5aWc5iE&t=137s) name Solandy and trying to achieve the same results.

A few things such as punycode had been depreciated so certain version of nodejs will not work with the tutorial.

looking to resolve this issue in the easiest way possible.

Comment: This looks similar -> https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4077/bigint-failed-to-load-bindings-pure-js-will-be-used-try-npm-run-rebuild-whe